How to Control Video Quality Switching for .m3u8 Files in Expo AV Video Component
I'm building a React Native app using Expo, and I'm trying to implement video quality switching for .m3u8 files with the Expo AV Video component.
Currently, I have a Cloudinary .m3u8 URL that automatically provides different video quality levels for adaptive streaming. However, I want to allow users to manually select the video quality (e.g., 240p, 480p, 720p) from a list of available options.
Here’s what I need help with:
Getting the Quality List: Is there a way to retrieve a list of available video qualities from the .m3u8 file in Expo AV, or any workaround to get these quality options?
Setting Video Quality: Once I have the available quality levels, how can I let users switch between them using Expo AV Video? I couldn't find any built-in methods for this in the Expo AV documentation.
    import { Video, ResizeMode } from 'expo-av';

    <Video
        ref={videoRef}
        style={{width:'100%',height:'100%'}}
        source={{uri:file.playback_url}} //https://res.cloudinary.com/hypercodez/video/upload/sp_auto/v1730660747/videos/ekhj7b58rmoym2tupbu4.m3u8
        useNativeControls={true}
        resizeMode={ResizeMode.CONTAIN}
        isLooping={false}
        shouldPlay={played}
        onPlaybackStatusUpdate={(status) => setStatus(() => status)}
        progressUpdateIntervalMillis={500}
        rate={rate}    
    >

Things I've Tried:
Checking the Expo AV documentation but couldn’t find explicit methods for quality switching.
Exploring manual switching, but .m3u8 URLs don’t provide separate qualities in a straightforward way.
Question: Is there a workaround or additional library that integrates well with Expo to handle video quality switching for .m3u8 files, or does anyone have any code examples for custom quality selection?
